# JAXB Unmarshalling json with unknown field having special character throwing DOM exception invalid character error while trying to map XMLAnyElement

Tags: json, web-services, jaxb, special-characters, unmarshalling

I am retrieving a json from Web service which is having a field with special character `#`. for example `i#d`.

example json file :

```
student : {
        "name" : "xyz",
        "randomfield" : null,
        "address" : {
                 "door number" : "2/3/45A",
                 "street" : "arundalpet",
                 "city"   : "newyork"
              }
        "i#d" : "some value"
    }
```

and my entity is

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Student {

    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    private String name;
    
    @XmlElement(name ="address")
    private Address address;

    // add a catch all value
    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    private Object[] unknown;

    .... getters and setters of name and address

}
```

Here I have added unknown field to catch all unknown fields which are not required to map to our fields. Reason for adding this is : `Address` is not getting mapped if for ex: `randomfield` which is unknown field having `null`. So, to avoid this I handled unknown fields with `XmlAnyElement`.

If I remove unknown field in the entity, I am not getting any error but with Address as null.

So, I need this unknown field handling and special characters handling for unmarshalling json using JAXB.

Could anyone please help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a workaround using which you should be able to `unmarshal` it. I don't think there is a direct approach using `JAXB/Moxy`. Following is the code:

```
import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import jakarta.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.ByteArraySource;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class UnmarshallingJSON {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, TransformerException, IOException {
        final InputStream inputStream = com.newJAXB.UnmarshallingJSON.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("student.json");
        final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
        final JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[]{Student.class}, properties);
        final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();


        String temp = "";
        StringBuffer textFileContent = new StringBuffer();
        while ((temp = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (temp.contains("i#d")) {
                temp = temp.replaceAll("#", "");
                textFileContent.append(temp);
            } else {
                textFileContent.append(temp);
            }
        }
        bufferedReader.close();

        StreamSource streams = new ByteArraySource(textFileContent.toString().getBytes());
        Student student = unmarshaller.unmarshal(streams, Student.class).getValue();
        System.out.println(student);
    }
}
```

Following is the `Student`:

```
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

import java.util.List;

@XmlRootElement(name = "Student")
@XmlType(name = "Student", propOrder = {"name", "address", "unknown"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@ToString
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Student {

    private String name;
    private Address address;

    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    private List<Object> unknown;
}


@Data
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Address {
    private String street;
    private String city;
}
```

Following is the `JSON`:

```
{
  "randomID": null,
  "name": "MyName",
  "address": {
    "street": "123Street",
    "city": "MyCity"
  },
  "i#d": "some value"
}
```

Comment: It resolves the problem with #, but what about other special characters. I need a permanent solution where it will handle the similar issues later. Can using Jackson solves all the issues in a direct way? or are there any disadvantages with Jackson?

Comment: If I were you then I would go for the `Jackson Deserilization` approach for JSON rather than `Unmarshalling` using `JAXB`. I would use `JAXB` only for `Marshalling and Unmarshalling` XML documents. For JSON Jackson would be the right fit as it provides various features during the `Serialization and Deserilization`.

Comment: You can use `@AnySetter` in `Jackson` to get all the `Unmarpped` values and store it within `Map<String,Object>`. Similar to what you are doing using the `@XmlAnyElement`.